# Perform more than one operation in scala's foreach?

Tags: scala, function, foreach

Let's say I have this ListBuffer that I am filling in a scala foreach like the following:

```
Tokens.foreach(t => tokens+=new Token(t._1.toString()))
```

i am wondering whether it is possible to perform another operation at the same time for-example adding to a string something like:

```
Tokens.foreach(t => tokens+=new Token(t._1.toString()), posTagString+=t._2.toString())
```

the 2nd example results in a *"too many arguments (2) for method foreach"* error. Is there a way to do this or shall I just stick too the form of:

```
   for(x<-Tokens){

    }
```

Comment: Try writing both operations in different lines or separate them with a semi-colon.

Comment: you need a curly bracket and apply what @philantrovert is suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this? :

```
Tokens.foreach{t => 
  tokens+=new Token(t._1.toString())
  posTagString+=t._2.toString()
}
```

Comment: Sanchit, you should give credit to philantrovert . :) don't you think so?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that he has already posted the answer. How can I give credit to @philantrovert?

Comment: see the first comment in question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by using map too

```
Tokens.map(t => {
  tokens += new Token(t._1.toString())
  posTagString += t._2.toString()
})
```